# Importing Fonts from JAR file

Tags: java, fonts, jar, io

I've attempted to create a custom font using the following method, however it throws an exception :

> Stream closed

and nothing happens! How can I import a ttf file from my JAR and use it in Java 2D! I'v managed to get it to work with external files, but it just doesn't work with an InputStream!

```
 public Font gameFont(String filename, float fontSize) {
    Font myfont = null;
     Font myfontReal = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("com/or/dungeon/" + filename));

        myfont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
        myfontReal = myfont.deriveFont(fontSize);
        is.close();
    } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return myfontReal;
}
```

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: Maybe the `is.close()` shouldn't be done. I think the second call to `gameFont` is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a leading slash.  Without it, it is searching relative to the class making the call. Try:

`this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/or/dungeon/" + filename));`

Alternatively, try:

`this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/or/dungeon/" + filename));`